# How to detect if a function pointer comes from a shared library or the main executable?

Tags: c++, linux, addr2line

I'm using `backtrace` and `backtrace_symbols` to get a stacktrace when a custom exception is thrown in my program (for now, on Linux... Ubuntu specifically)

```cpp
trace_size = backtrace(stack_traces, MAX_STACK_FRAMES);
messages = backtrace_symbols(stack_traces, trace_size);
```

From the stacktrace, I'm able to loop over each frame and extract an address that the program was at for this frame.

I get two types of addresses depending on where a function was defined:

1. A library address:

```bash
/path/to/library.so(mangled_function_name+0x75) [0x7f02bcdfa849]
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2. executable address:

```bash
/path/to/executable(mangled_function_name?+0x90) [0x403336]
                                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

`[0x7f02bcdfa849]` and `[0x403336]` are where my concerns lie...

I want to pass these addresses to `addr2line`.

However, for addresses belonging to shared libraries, this won't work. I learned that I first need to calculate the offset of the parsed address from the base address that the library was loaded at.

```bash
addr2line -e /path/to/library.so 0x7f02bcdfa849 # won't work
# or
addr2line -e /path/to/executable 0x403336 # works just fine
```

I know I can use `::dladdr` to find the base address and find the offset from that.

But, how can I tell, at runtime, whether I need to do this transformation? As in, how can I tell if an address belongs to a shared library at runtime?

I've tried simply checking if the `.so` shows up in the frame of the stacktrace but that feels... wrong.

Comment: This cannot be done with any degree of realibility. Thanks to ASLR the addresses are likely to change each time the executable runs. Although some conclusions can be made based on large address ranges, I would not rely on that myself and expect all promises to be broken with the next kernel update.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so you claim that gdb is impossible? Interesting...

Comment: Have you read the man page for dladdr? What does it say about sending in an address that does not belong to any shared library?

Comment: "If the address specified in addr could not be matched to a shared object, then these functions return 0" but this seems to returns a non-zero valuable even for functions in the "main" executable.

Comment: A dynamically-linked executable is a shared object too.

Comment: man page for `dladdr` isn't saying that it returns anything helpful to distinguish linked library v.s. linked exe BUT it did point me to `dladdr1` which may be more promising

Comment: `/proc/self/maps`. The information should also be some programmable way but the bottom line is you can just parse this file.

Answer (score 0):

`::dladdr1` has the information I needed.

Given I have `addr_ptr` which is either the address in a shared library or in the shared exe, I can get the base address to subtract from `addr_ptr` by calling into `::dladdr1` and using the returned `::link_map` data structure.

The `::link_map` has a field called `l_addr` which is 0 for the exe and non-zero for linked libraries.

So given an `addr_ptr` that has the parsed address:

```cpp
#include <dlfcn.h> // for ::dladdr1
#include <link.h> // for ::link_map
...

    const void* final_ptr = nullptr;
    ::Dl_info dli_;
    if (::link_map *lm = nullptr;
        ::dladdr1(addr_ptr, &dli_, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&lm), RTLD_DL_LINKMAP)) {
        if (lm != nullptr) {
            auto lib_delta_int = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(addr_ptr) -
                                 reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(lm->l_addr);

            final_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const void *>(lib_delta_int);
        }
    }
```

`final_ptr` has the correct value now to pass to `addr2line`